# How can I get a high quality profile picture using React Native Facebook SDK GraphRequest?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a high resolution picture using the React Native Facebook SDK, however the default image quality is very poor. It's 50x50 and very low resolution.

**Request:**

```
new GraphRequest('/135121013672357',
  {
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        string: 'picture'
      }
    }
  },
  _responseInfoCallback
)
```

**Response**

```
{
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/16864988_145199975997794_4154735936748679550_n.jpg?oh=bb5f32ecb73dd9b8fb8ac45920e2ffc5&oe=593223A8"
    }
  },
  "id": "135121013672357"
}
```

Looking at [Facebook's Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/), there is a parameter, "type", whereby one can request a particular size (small, medium, large). What isn't clear however, is how to format that request.

```
picture?type=large // Error

picture{type:large} // 200 However, picture is omitted from Response
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using [Graph API field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion) to get the resource:

`picture.type(large)`

Comment: The phrases ".type" and "large" do not show in that documentation whatsoever

Answer (score 5):

You can also use .height and .width to get an even higher resolution picture or a resolution you need it at:

Example endpoint for `480x{any-width}` image:
`/me?fields=id,name,picture.height(480),[:other_fields]`

Example endpoint for `{any-height}x480` image:
`/me?fields=id,name,picture.width(480),[:other_fields]`

Example endpoint for maximum resolution image:
`/me?fields=id,name,picture.height(10000),[:others_fields]`

Official documentation is at the `/{node-id}/picture` page at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/.
And you can try the API out without debugging through the app at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example about how we can get a large Facebook user profile's picture on a simple way using the react-native-fbsdk package.

```
try {
  const currentAccessToken = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()

  const graphRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
    accessToken: currentAccessToken.accessToken,
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        string: 'picture.type(large)',
      },
    },
  }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } else {
      console.log(result.picture.data.url)
    }
  })

  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(graphRequest).start()
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: this get the current url, but after enter to that url, is getting downloaded whole image, given url => `https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=10218466988484935&height=200&width=200&ext=1553452039&hash=AeSo-QHBXC1UZzxK`

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this?? im under the same situation as @DanteCervantes

Answer (score 1):

```
onFBLogin = async () => {
        try{
        const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
           'public_profile',
           'email',
        ]);
       const tokenObj = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            '/me',
            {
                accessToken: tokenObj.accessToken,
                parameters: {
                    fields: {
                        string: 'email,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,address,picture.type(large)',
                    },
                },
            },
            this.infoResponseCallback,
        );
       new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error",err)
    }

infoResponseCallback = (error,success) =>{
        if(error){
              console.log("eeeeeeeeeee",error)
        }else{
              console.log(success)
        }
    }
```